# Setting height to match contraint in constrainlyout is shrinking the height of the view

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have 3 card layouts in ConstraintLayout. I wanted to match the height of the second and third card layouts in the row to match with the first card layout.

So I added the lines conditions TopToTop of and BottomToBottom Of. And I set the height to 0dp (match constraints in design view). Surprisingly, second and third card layout heights are being centred and not matched. Please help me with this issue.

And for some reason, I am getting double shaded images in each card layout. I am not sure why.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlHeader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40dp"
            android:background="@color/action_color"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_20dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_semibold"
                android:text="@string/pick_a_service"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_home1"
            style="@style/cardHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/card_home5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rlHeader">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/featureText1"
                    style="@style/textHome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="@string/verification" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_home5"
            style="@style/cardHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent5"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/card_home1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/card_home8"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/card_home1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/card_home1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/featureText5"
                    style="@style/textHome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="@string/verification" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_home8"
            style="@style/cardHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/card_home1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/card_home5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/card_home1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/featureText8"
                    style="@style/textHome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="@string/verification" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_50dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/progress_dialog_back"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
                android:max="100"
                android:padding="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:progress="0"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: change you constraints layout to relative layout

Comment: As I checked in my studio your all three cardview in depend on first one. You want same like that right?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Yes. It makes them get aligned with equal spaces between them.

Comment: But I think it's working see. http://prntscr.com/n0c0i9, http://prntscr.com/n0c0ak

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan the same code I posted?

Comment: yes, nothing I changed.Try to run in device and check there how it looks?

Comment: It's weird. I also took the screenshot from my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the XML file, hope this helps:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">



            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/label_a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_b"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:text="Verification" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/label_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_a"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/label_c"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
             >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:text="Verification" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/label_c"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/label_b"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
               >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:text="Verification" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Tip for the future - please don't use nested viewGroups inside `ConstaintLayout ` - it is really bad for performance and not at all the purpose of `ConstaintLayout `. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: ConstaintLayout is best for performance https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html

Comment: please show view design ConstaintLayout  if possiable

Answer (score 0):

ConstaintLayout is not meant to have inner view groups. Its all about flat view hierarchy - so you can avoid using all of your inner view groups and just use [chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html):

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```